# Forums for text mining/similarity

Tags: text-mining, forums

I am aware that stackoverflow is a programming oriented forum that helps coders to solve bugs . But i have plenty of conceptual doubts in text mining techniques / information retrieval and semantic similarity .

Please suggest a forum where they discuss these concepts so that i can putforth my doubts in that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

And before https://stats.stackexchange.com/ there was http://metaoptimize.com/qa/, which is still fairly active.